# How to add 2 NSNumbers?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Why does the following addition fail with the error below?

```
NSNumber *five = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
NSNumber *three = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
NSNumber *eight = [five intValue] + [three intValue];
```

Implicit conversion of int to NSNumber is disallowed with ARC

Comment: Is this just an example because there is no reason to use `NSNumber` for any of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use modern syntax:

```
NSNumber *five = @5;
NSNumber *three = @3;
NSNumber *eight = @([five intValue] + [three intValue]);
```

For sake of completeness: The error is caused by trying to assign an `int` value to an `NSNumber` variable. The value must be wrapped.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just assign an `int` to an `NSNumber`. You'd have to use `NSNumber`'s `numberWithInt:` to instantiate an `NSNumber` object from an `int` value:

```
NSNumber *eight = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([five intValue] + [three intValue])];
```

OR you can do:

```
NSNumber *eight = @([five intValue] + [three intValue]);
```

But you can't convert from `int` to `NSNumber` without calling some function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
NSNumber *eight = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([five intValue] + [three intValue])];
```

If you can, avoid using `NSNumber` for numeric operations (such as addition) and use `int` values instead. Just create a `NSNumber` when you finally need it (i.e. to use it in a cocoa library call).

Answer (score 0):

`[five intValue] + [three intValue]` does not result in an `NSNumber` object, it results in an `int`, the same way `5 + 3` does. This explains your error, `Implicit conversion of int to NSNumber is disallowed with ARC`

The line of code you want is: `NSNumber *eight = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[five intValue] + [three intValue]];`